# What does a wait_for_ready warning mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, asynchronous, swift, warnings

I'm writing a Swift project right now that deals with pulling files from Dropbox using the Sync SDK and storing them in the tmp directory folder on my device. Occasionally though when I select one of the files to be loaded it stalls for a few seconds before continuing and I am given the message:

`[WARNING] thr: env.cpp:113: wait_for_ready should not be called on the main thread`.

Based on my log it seems to occur when I am writing NSData to a file path.

Would appreciate if anyone had a theory one why this would be happening, or any documentation I should read. Is it something to do with a synchronous request happening in the background?

Comment: It actually sounds like a synchronous request happening on the main thread (i.e. foreground). I haven't used the Dropbox SDK though, so I don't know what would cause that. Maybe post how you're using their sync API?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The end result was that I realize I was using the wrong Dropbox SDK for what I was trying to do. I tore down my project and implement the Core SDK instead and everything worked perfectly!